# Spring MVC - jsp not rendering

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm just starting with Spring MVC trying to create a new project, and came accross an issue for which no manual or tutorial seems to help...

I have set up a simple application with no logic, just trying to get Spring configured properly. The controller just returns the name of a view to be displayed, but the view resolver is not rendering the jsp, and returning a 404 error....

Any help is greatly appreciated.

My web.xml is:

```
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>openstats</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>openstats</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <display-name>OpenStats API Server</display-name>
</web-app>
```

An my openstats-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.openstats.api.controller"/>

    <!-- Enable to request mappings PER METHOD -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <!-- Enable annotated POJO @Controller -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <!-- Define the view resolver to use jsp files within the jsp folder -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"><value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value></property>
        <property name="prefix"><value>/jsp/</value></property>
        <property name="suffix"><value>.jsp</value></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

The controller itself has no logic whatsoever, it's simply:

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/products.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView listProducts(HttpServletRequest request) {

        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
        return model;
    }
}
```

The controller is reached, the issue is when attempting to render...

I set up log4j in debug, and this is part of what I get:

> 02:08:19,702 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:1094 - Testing handler adapter
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter@397b6074]
>   02:08:19,803 DEBUG
>   HandlerMethodInvoker:134 - Invoking
>   request handler method: public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView
>   org.openstats.api.controller.ProductController.listProducts(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
>   02:08:19,833 DEBUG
>   DefaultListableBeanFactory:1367 -
>   Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean
>   with name 'index' 02:08:19,876 DEBUG
>   InternalResourceViewResolver:81 -
>   Cached view [index] 02:08:19,877 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:1181 - Rendering
>   view
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView:
>   name 'index'; URL [/jsp/index.jsp]] in
>   DispatcherServlet with name
>   'openstats' 02:08:19,877 DEBUG
>   JstlView:240 - Rendering view with
>   name 'index' with model {} and static
>   attributes {} 02:08:19,923 DEBUG
>   JstlView:234 - Forwarding to resource
>   [/jsp/index.jsp] in
>   InternalResourceView 'index'
>   02:08:19,926 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:955 -
>   DispatcherServlet with name
>   'openstats' determining Last-Modified
>   value for [/api-server/jsp/index.jsp]
>   02:08:19,927 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:1054 - Testing
>   handler map
>   [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping@440c4cee]
>   in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'openstats' 02:08:19,928 DEBUG
>   DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping:179 -
>   No handler mapping found for
>   [/jsp/index.jsp] 02:08:19,929 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:962 - No handler
>   found in getLastModified 02:08:19,937
>   DEBUG DispatcherServlet:781 -
>   DispatcherServlet with name
>   'openstats' processing request for
>   [/api-server/jsp/index.jsp]
>   02:08:19,938 DEBUG
>   DispatcherServlet:843 - Bound request
>   context to thread: GET
>   /api-server/products.do HTTP/1.1

My jsp folder is right within "webapp" and the index.jsp file exists.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's odd here is that once the InternalResourceViewResolver finds the correct JSP, the DispatcherServlet starts treating it like a request and is looking for a controller to handle the URN /api-server/jsp/index.jsp
Could you post the contents of the JSP?
Is there any other configuration that could be causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

I do have the same problem with Spring 3.x.
Any progress so far?

**EDIT:** 
I figured it out myself :-) I used the following servletmapping:

```
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-frontcontroller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Editing the url-pattern to e.g. *.do fixes the problem of not rendering the JSP. 
But this leaves the question how this is possible with your url-pattern.

Comment: I had this exact problem too, thanks for pointing it out! I guess I'll have to settle on an extension.

Comment: Is this behaviour documented somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

Does your web.xml define index.jsp in the welcome-file-list, if so it may be getting overridden. Try changing the jsp name to products.jsp.

e.g.

```
@Controller
public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/products.do", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String handleRequest() {
          return "products";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

doesn't your .jsp and your .do conflict? since a file cannot end with both .jsp and .do .. therefore it will never resolve... so you should get rid of .jsp or change your url pattern to  /*

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

by

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
```

Works in my case.